# Parsing a massive CSV into JSON using Java

Tags: java, json, csv

I'm trying to parse a huge CSV (56595 lines) into a `JSONArray` but it's taking a considerable amount of time. This is what my code looks like and it takes ~17 seconds to complete. I'm limiting my results based on one of the columns but the code still has to go through the entire CSV file.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I've excluded the `catch`'s, `finally`'s and `throws` to save space.

[File](http://www.iso-ne.com/transform/csv/fiveminlmp/currentrollinginterval)

**Code**

```
...
BufferedReader reader = null;
String line = "";

//jArray is retrieved by an ajax call and used in a graph 
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
    //url = CSV file
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    String[] row = line.split(",");

                     //skips first three rows
                     if(row.length > 2){
                        //map = 4011
                        if(row[1].equals(map)) {
                           json.put("col0", row[0]);
                           json.put("col1", row[1]);
                           json.put("col2", row[2]);
                           json.put("col3", row[3]);
                           json.put("col4", row[4]);
                           json.put("col5", row[5]);
                           json.put("col6", row[6]);

                           jArray.put(json);
                        }
                    }
             return jArray;
            }
...
```

Comment: If you remove the parsing and just read the file line by line, how long does it take?  The point I'm making is that have you identified where the problem lies?

Comment: Did the JSONArray have initial space allocation? B/c, if so, every time you add some data to it and the size of array is "crossed", the entire array will copy himself with a new size.

Comment: @Neil ~25 seconds.

Comment: I didn't work with JSON, so I suppose that my previous comment isn't relevant.

Comment: How often occurs does the expression `row[1].equals(map)` evaluate to `true`? And how many items would contain `row`?

Comment: And another question: What is `jArray`, and how is it expected to be eventually used?

Comment: @LittleSanti the code returns 49 lines which is correct for `map=4011.` That's out of 56595 lines. I added a description of `jArray`

Comment: So if you just read the CSV it takes 25 seconds and if you parse it to JSON, it takes 17 seconds? Seems like the issue here is downloading the JSON not optimising your parsing. So perhaps your network connection is the bottleneck?

Comment: @Tarmo I am parsing a similar CSV from the same source with ~1200 lines using this same method and it returns in less than a second

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the main delay will predictably be at **downloading the file from HTTP**, so all your chances will rest upon optimizing your code. So, based upon the info you provided, I can suggest some enhancements to optimize your algorithm:

1. It was a good idea to process the input file in streaming mode, reading line by line with a with `BufferedReader`. Usually it is a good practice to set an explicit buffer size (BufferedReader's default size is 8Kb), but being the source a network connection, I doubt it will be any better in this case. Anyway, you should try 16Kb, for instance.
2. Since the number of output items is very low (49, you said), it doesn't matter to store it in an array (for a higher amount, I would have recommend you to chose another collection, like LinkedList), but it is always useful to **pre-size** it with an estimated size. In JSONArray, I suppose it would be enough to put a `null` item at position 100 (for example) at the beginning of your method.
3. The biggest deal I think of is the line `line.split(",")`, because that makes the program **go through the whole line, duplicate its contents character by character into an array, and the worst of it all, for eventually use it only in a 0.1% of cases**.

And there might be even a worse drawback: Merely splitting by comma might be not a good way to properly parse a JSON line. I mean: Are you **sure** the json values **cannot** contain a comma as part of user data?

Well, to solve this problem I suggest you to code your own json custom parsing algorithm, which might be a little hard, but it will be worth the effort. You must code a state machine in which you detect the second value and, if the key coincides with the filtering value ("4011"), continue parsing the rest of the line. In this way, you will save a big amount of time and memory.